# Can't create any partial views in asp.net mvc 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting this error when trying to load a partial view, and I don't know what the issue is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
>   dictionary is of type 'CDB.OrderM', but this dictionary requires a
>   model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CDB.tblItem]'.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            OrderM om = new OrderM();
            List<tblItem> tList = db.Query<tblItem>("Select * from tblItem").ToList<tblItem>();
            ViewBag.tList = tList;
            return View(om);
        }

        public ActionResult Reqitem()
        {
            //tblItem ti= db.Query<tblItem>("select * from tblItem");
            var ti = db.Query<tblItem>("select * from tblItem");
            return PartialView("_rawmat",ti);
        }


My Partial View codes are-


 @model IEnumerable<CDB.tblItem>

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MeasuringUnit)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quantity)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BagSz)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MeasuringUnit)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BagSz)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>
```

and Index view codes are...

```
@model CDB.OrderM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    var tList = ViewBag.tList;
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>OrderM</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OdrId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OdrId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OdrId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderNo)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderNo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderNo)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OdrDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OdrDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OdrDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OdrQty)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OdrQty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OdrQty)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OdrAmount)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OdrAmount)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OdrAmount)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pod)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pod)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pod)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
@Html.Partial("_rawmat")
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Clearly your `_rawmat` view expects a list of `CDB.tblitem` and not a single one. Check the `@model ...` definition in your partial view.

Comment: Can you post the header of the `_rawmat` partial view?

Comment: Is there another option for creating partial views???

Comment: @MNAH: Have you seen my answer telling you the proper way to include this child action?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think the issue is in the second call of `@Html.Partial("_rawmat")` inside your `Index`.

It does not pass a model parameter, so it passed the default one, which is a `CDB.OrderM`.

Use this instead (it renders the action instead of the partial view):

```
@Html.Action("Reqitem")
```

Comment: This looks like web forms syntax, not MVC.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Hofman CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you want to do is change `@Html.Partial("_rawmat")` to `@Html.Action("Reqitem")`. This is because your original statement says go straight to the view and since you haven't passed a model it will pass the same model as the view that it is included on.

So if you use `@Html.Partial("_rawmat")` on your index view it will pass the model that it has which is of type `OrderM` and not actually call the action you have written at all.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why you people are missing out the available syntax to call a partial view with a model

```
{@Html.RenderPartial("_PartialView",List<CDB.tblItem>) }
```

Where I assume the partial view uses the Model of type `List<CDB.tblItem>`.

If you want to populate the model with any values. just before the above syntax use

```
@{

//code to populate your model

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your partial view is expecting a List, then change the method like this...

```
public ActionResult Reqitem()
        {
            //tblItem ti= db.Query<tblItem>("select * from tblItem");
            var ti = db.Query<tblItem>("select * from tblItem").ToList();//notice to List
            return PartialView("_rawmat",ti);
        }
```

I have added `.ToList()` to the end of the query.

Comment: What error are you getting, can you post the code to your view?